# How to get all image urls in product collection? How to apply group_concat here?

Tags: product, collection, product-images, product-collection

I'm trying to get product collection with all of its images url. Is there any other way to get product collection with all of it image urls?

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField(
            'qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left')
        ->joinField(
            'imgurls',
            'catalog/product_attribute_media_gallery',
            'value',
            'entity_id = entity_id',
            null,
            'left')
        ->groupByAttribute('entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToSort('updated_at','asc')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array('from' => $updateAtFilter))
        ->setPageSize($transferLimit)
;
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE! :) Might I suggest that you add detail to your question? Folks here will be able to help you out much better if you clearly describe the problem, what you have tried and what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to get product collection with all of its images url. Is there any other way to get product collection with all of it image urls ?

Answer (score 2):

The way Magento stores image will make it difficult if not impossible to get them in one query together with all the other data. Per image type a new row is created in the table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` which means that if you want 5 images for example the query would return 5 rows.

The thumbnail and small image of a product are stored in the the flat tables that means you can access those when calling a product collection. In case you want all images from a product the easiest way is to use the `getMediaGalleryImages()` method

Comment: Is there any way to get by using group_concat ?

Comment: like this 'productids' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.product_id SEPARATOR "|")') in salesorder collection object returns all product ids.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the URLs directly from the database query, no chance. The URLs are not stored in the database, just a relative file path, from which the URL is derived in PHP.

However, if you are satisfied with a comma separated list of these file paths, it should be possible if you change your code like this:

```
    ->joinField(
        'imgurls',
        'catalog/product_attribute_media_gallery',
        new Zend_Db_Expr("GROUP_CONCAT({{table}}.value SEPARATOR ','"),
        'entity_id = entity_id',
        null,
        'left')
```

An alternative would be using `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4::addGroupConcatColumn()`:

```
Mage::getResourceHelper('core')->addGroupConcatColumn(
    $collection->getSelect(), 'imgurls', 'media_gallery.value');
```

(after joining the media gallery attribute table with the alias `media_gallery`)

Answer (score 1):

try these it worked for me

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image');

foreach($collection as $product){
    (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
    //Or with resize
    (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(200);
}
```

Comment: I guess there is no 'image' attribute to select.