# Get all images besides thumb, small and base

Tags: collection, magento-1, product-images, product-collection

Following up to this question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118096/in-static-block-call-phtml-file-for-specific-product-id/) I am wondering with my code I have right now

```
<?php
$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('product_url')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('product_reviews')
    ->joinAttribute('image', 'catalog_product/image', 'entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $this->getPid())
    ->setPageSize(1);

if ($_collection->getSize()) {
    $_product = $_collection->getFirstItem();
    $_productImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
    $_productName = $_product->getName();
    $_productReview = $_product->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false);
    $_productPrice = $_product->getPrice();
    $_productUrl = $_product->getProductUrl();
}
?>
```

Then i thought i can iterate through the gallery images like this

```
<?php
$sliderImage = array();
if(count($_product->getMediaGalleryImages())) {
    foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image) {
        $bannerImage = $_image->getSlider();
        if ($bannerImage) {
            $sliderImage[]  = $_image;
        }
    }
}?>
```

I always get the base image of the product.

However I have around 5-8 images per product, and besides the standard ones, base, small and thumb i would like a different picture to be loaded here.

**Is it possible to somehow get a different image? I have them all in a sort order so for example I would like the image with sort order 3.**

Comment: What does `$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()` gives you ?

Comment: I have updated it, does not work, also I thought i can get the product reviews but that wont work either

Comment: Or do I have to change the selection for the collection to get the Media Gallery Images?

Comment: Yeah try that maybe

Comment: @Raphael at Digital Pianism, i tried that but dont really know how to change that join attribute. Refering to this [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11678/how-to-get-all-image-urls-in-product-collection-how-to-apply-group-concat-here) it seems like it is not possible so easily and I have to change the code in total.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism any idea how i could do it even with loading the whole product ?

Comment: I need to investigate I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how i did it now

```
<?php
$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('product_url')
    ->joinAttribute('image', 'catalog_product/image', 'entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $this->getPid())
    ->setPageSize(1);

if ($_collection->getSize()) {
    $_product = $_collection->getFirstItem();
    $_productImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
    $_productName = $_product->getName();
    $_productPrice = $_product->getPrice();
    $_productUrl = $_product->getProductUrl();
}
?>

<?php
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->load($this->getPid());
?>
<?php 
$imagepath = array();
$productImage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getPid());
foreach ($productImage->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                     $imagepath[] = $image->getUrl();
}  
?>
```

And then I can access all Images with $imagepath[X]

where X stands for the Sort order number.

Also with the SummaryData I can then access the Review Count and Rating.

So actually @Raphael at Digital Pianism was correct